# Edit Module Bootstrap size to match bootstrap 3

Tags: module, overrides, bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to customize / add new options to the back office module advanced tab?

We already have "bootstrap size" option, but since now I'm using Bootstrap 3 I want to use 2 more extra fields for tablet and phone sizes.

I think the solution is to override the model function preprocessForm() under /administrator/components/com_modules/models/module.php and add a new line to load an extra xml..

Is it possible? how can I do it?

Thanks in advance,
Pestana

Comment: I already looked to https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core to try to override the model module.php but with no success, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Closed as unclear!?
Module override, add functionality to the back office module view, is this unclear?

Comment: I have a solution!
I created a plugin that adds a new XML to the form...
If anyone needs this please write it here, maybe the moderator can help me posting the answer ;)